# FactoryGirl : 'Factory not registered' error when added a factory to a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I've got 2 factories files

spec/factories/cars.rb

spec/factories/users.rb

A user can have many cars and I would like to create a special trait for this case.

Into my car factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :car do
    ...

    trait :is_blue do
        color 'blue'
    end
  end

  factory :blue_car, parent: :car do
    is_blue 
  end
end
```

My user factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    ...

    trait :with_cars do
      cars  [ FactoryGirl.create(:blue_car) ]
    end

  end


  factory :user_with_cars, parent: :user  do
    with_cars
  end

end
```

When I want to use the 'user_with_cars' factory into my 'user_spec' file I've got a 'Factory not registered: blue_car' error

Example :

```
context 'with cars' do
  subject { create(:user_with_cars) }

  it 'should make some stuff' do
    expect(subject.cars).not_to be_empty

    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I change the way I create relations.
In the trait wich add relations I use the 'after(:create)' callback.

spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    ...

    trait :with_cars do
      after(:create) do |user|
        user.cars << create(:blue_car)
      end
   end


   factory :user_with_cars, parent: :user  do
     with_cars
   end
end
```